# How to modify complex JSON data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have below JSON data & I need to modify the values or remove some properties.

```
 {
"actions": {
"canUpdateAbc": true,
"canUpdateXyz": true  
},
"criteria": [
{
  "criteriaType": {
    "code": "CCode",
    "value": "C Code"
  },
  "processType": {
    "code": "PType",
    "value": "C"
  },
  "values": [
    "123456"
  ]
},
{
  "criteriaType": {
    "code": "ACode",
    "value": "A Code"
  },
  "processType": {
    "code": "PType",
    "value": "R"
  },
  "values": [
    "567890"
  ]
}
],
"outcome": {
"code": "create",
"value": "Always create"
},
"unlessCriteria": []
}
```

& I need to modify processType. i.e processType = undefined or need to remove the property.

Output should be

```
{
"actions": {
"canUpdateAbc": true,
"canUpdateXyz": true  
},
 "criteria": [
 {
  "criteriaType": {
    "code": "CCode",
    "value": "C Code"
  },      
  "values": [
    "123456"
  ]
},
{
  "criteriaType": {
    "code": "ACode",
    "value": "A Code"
  },     
  "values": [
    "567890"
  ]
}
],
"outcome": {
"code": "create",
"value": "Always create"
},
"unlessCriteria": []
}
```

I have tried like this..

```
 const rules = rule.criteria?.map((m) => {
    m.processType = undefined;
    return m;
   });
```

& Its not working. I get only criteria, not entire JSON data.

How to achieve in Typescript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the spread operator `...` to spread the original object. This should work:

```
const rules = {
  ...rule,
  criteria: rule.criteria?.map((m) => {
    m.processType = undefined;
    return m;
  }),
};
```

You can consider `delete m.processType` instead of setting it to `undefined`, if you prefer.

Alternatively, you can use this if you don't mind mutating the original object:

```
rule.criteria?.forEach((m) => {
    delete m.processType;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is not to reassign the `rule` value with only the criterias array inside, let's call your json data is `data`, you should rewrite your code like below

```
const rule = {
  ...data,
  criteria: data.criteria.map((crt) => {
    crt.processType = undefined;
    return crt;
  }),
}
```

This code keeps all data property and reassign only criteria array with `processType` in criteria item has been reassign to undefined.

If you're familiar with `lodash`, you can solve your problem with `omit`, a bit easier to read and declarative. (Lodash also have a lot of useful feature to manipulate data)

```
import { omit } from 'lodash';
const rule = {
  ...data,
  criteria: data.criteria.map(crt => omit(crt, 'processType')),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an another possible solution

parse the JSON data into object => Modify `processType` property within each object in `criteria` array => convert the modified object back into a JSON string.

```
 // Parse the JSON data into an object
const jsonData = `{
  "actions": {
    "canUpdateAbc": true,
    "canUpdateXyz": true
  },
  "criteria": [
    {
      "criteriaType": {
        "code": "CCode",
        "value": "C Code"
      },
      "processType": {
        "code": "PType",
        "value": "C"
      },
      "values": [
        "123456"
      ]
    },
    {
      "criteriaType": {
        "code": "ACode",
        "value": "A Code"
      },
      "processType": {
        "code": "PType",
        "value": "R"
      },
      "values": [
        "567890"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "outcome": {
    "code": "create",
    "value": "Always create"
  },
  "unlessCriteria": []
}`;

const parsedData = JSON.parse(jsonData);

// Modify the processType property within each criteria object
if (parsedData.criteria) {
  parsedData.criteria.forEach((criteriaItem: any) => {
    delete criteriaItem.processType;
  });
}

// Convert the modified object back into a JSON string
const modifiedJsonData = JSON.stringify(parsedData, null, 2);

console.log(modifiedJsonData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it this way:(personally, I like the above answer by twharmon)

```
 rules.criteria = rules.criteria?.map((m) => {
    m.processType = undefined;
    return m;
   });
```

Now if you see rules object, criteria will have your required processType. This is because "The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array."